# How do I check the checkbox programmatically in c# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have dynamically created checkboxes in my winform. Now I want to update the check mark in these checkboxes. How do I do that? I have only the

> checkbox.Name

property to check mark the checkbox.
I have used

```
foreach (CheckBox box in chboxes)
 box.Checked = true;
```

where boxes is a List type and dynamically created checkboxes have been added to boxes.

```
chboxes.Add(chkbox);
```

**Problem:** checkboxes are not checked programmatically. That is my issue.

```
CheckBox chkbox = new CheckBox();
 chkbox.Name = "priv1";
 panel.Controls.Add(chkbox);
```

Comment: What went wrong with the current code? what you are expected? Please be more clear and specific

Comment: @un-lucky I want to check mark 2 out of 5 checkboxes (for example)

Comment: "What went wrong with the current code? " is still unanswered.... The code looks fine. IS the problem that the checkboxes are not checked? don't they appear at all? did your dog eat all your checkboxes?

Comment: @AparajitaSinha We can't infer your conditional requirement(s) like: on what basis you want to check/uncheck the checkbox unless you are keen to explain the requirement.

Comment: @MongZhu checkboxes are not checked programmatically. That is my issue.

Comment: What is `chboxes`? I mean what type of control is that?

Comment: do they appear on the form? Do you have some code where the line: `this.Controls.Add(myCheckBox);`  appears?

Comment: @un-lucky List<CheckBox> chboxes

Comment: @MongZhu checkboxes are present but I cannot check them programmatically

Comment: please post the entire code where you create the checkboxes and add them to the controls. Or did you add the checkboxes to the form via drag and drop in the designer?

Comment: @MongZhu I have added my code

Comment: @AparajitaSinha: I have added an answer, Please let me know whether it solve your issue or not

Comment: ok, look. A post should reflect the necessary steps and the code to reproduce the problem that you face. Up to now, your code shows that you have created 1 Checkbox and added this checkbox into the list. A loop is also there. But we don't know where this loop is called and whether it is ever executed. All the parts on their own should work and if someone will try it out it will work. The problem is still somewhere else. We just don't see it. Please post the site where you call the loop to check the checkboxes

Comment: if I see that you have accepted the answer by un-lucky. So I strongly assume that you have never added the created checkboxes to the list `chboxes`. Or that the list that you loop through is not the same list as the one where you stored it.

Comment: I did not know about this panel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()

Comment: @AparajitaSinha you don't need to. Your code should work fine. I am glad that you have found a solution to your problem. But you still don't know why it did not work. If you are satisfied it is ok, but I would not be. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SO you have added some  CheckBoxes to the UI, and you need to iterate them and change its checked property according to some condition. The following code will help you to do that, Let `panel` be the place where you added the checkboxes, then the code will iterate through all controls oftype CheckBox in that panel and change it's state:

```
foreach (CheckBox box in panel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    if(some condition here)
    {
        box.Checked = true; 
    }
}
```